# Cannot implement alternative session token with unicode

Tags: python, sqlite, session, unicode, flask

I'm trying to implement an alternative [session token](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#alternative-tokens). The idea is to reset `session_token` every time `get_id` is called, so (I think) the session would be less vulnerable to hijacks.

```
import os
from flask_login import UserMixin
from app import db, login_manager

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    session_token = db.Column(db.Unicode)

    def get_id(self):
        self.session_token = unicode(os.urandom(64), 'utf-8', 'ignore')
        return self.session_token

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(session_token):
    return User.query.filter_by(session_token=session_token).first()
```

However, I'm receiving this error:

> ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) You must not use 8-bit
>   bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit
>   bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that
>   you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

Seems that the problem has something to do with unicode, but I received no errors when testing `unicode(os.urandom(64), 'utf-8', 'ignore')` in the interactive shell.

Comment: And what is the **full** traceback of the exception you get? Have you checked if `session_token` passed *to* `load_user` is a string and not a `bytes` object?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, `session_token` passed to `load_user` is a string! How can it be?!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wait...It's `unicode` now...I can't understanding what's happening...

Comment: @MartijnPieters So the code above works now, but I don't know why it **is** working (or in other words, why it **wasn't** working)...

Comment: Did you at some point in the past not return a `unicode()` string and this was stored in a cookie perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters What a nice explanation! Maybe I just forgot to type `:w`(I'm a vimer) after `unicode()` is added... Anyway, after dozens of tests, the problem described in my question still can't be reproduced. So should I delete this post?